# Extract key value pair details from XML, using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to extract key value pairs from the examples below:

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<chatTranscript startAt="2016-11-03T08:29:13Z" sessionId="0001KaC1NSN60019">

<newParty userId="0079581AF5590023" timeShift="0" visibility="ALL" eventId="1">
    <userInfo personId="" userNick="10.50.24.202" userType="CLIENT" protocolType="FLEX" timeZoneOffset="120"/>
    <userData>
        <item key="GMSServiceId">c0aa6221-d5f9-4fdc-9f75-ed63e99b1f12</item>
        <item key="IdentifyCreateContact">3</item><item key="MediaType">chat</item>
        <item key="TimeZone">120</item><item key="_data_id">139-9a8ee95b-d3ba-43a2-93a9-08ed7965d63d</item>
        <item key="firstName">Mike</item>
        <item key="lastName">Kumm</item>
    </userData>
</newParty>

<newParty userId="007957F616780001" timeShift="1" visibility="ALL" eventId="1">
    <userInfo personId="" userNick="John Doe" userType="CLIENT" protocolType="FLEX" timeZoneOffset="120"/>
    <userData>
        <item key="GMSServiceId">5954d184-f89d-4f44-8c0f-a772d458b353</item>
        <item key="IdentifyCreateContact">3</item>
        <item key="MediaType">chat</item><item key="TimeZone">120</item>
        <item key="_data_id">139-e9826bf5-c5a4-40e5-a729-2cbdb4776a43</item>
        <item key="firstName">John</item><item key="first_name">John</item>
        <item key="lastName">Doe</item>
        <item key="last_name">Doe</item>
        <item key="location_lat">37.8197</item>
        <item key="location_long">-122.4786</item>
        <item key="userDisplayName">John Doe</item>
    </userData>
</newParty>

<newParty userId="0079581874B50010" timeShift="0" visibility="ALL" eventId="1">
    <userInfo personId="" userNick="John" userType="CLIENT" protocolType="FLEX" timeZoneOffset="0"/>
    <userData>
        <item key="EmailAddress">dskim@gmail.com</item>
        <item key="FirstName">John</item>
        <item key="IdentifyCreateContact">3</item>
        <item key="LastName">Doe</item>
        <item key="MediaType">chat</item>
        <item key="TimeZone">120</item>
    </userData>
</newParty>

</chatTranscript>
```

For example, for the first new user that is added I would like to obtain the following information:

GMSServiceId: c0aa6221-d5f9-4fdc-9f75-ed63e99b1f12
IdentifyCreateContact: 3, MediaType: chat, TimeZone: 120, _data_id: 139-9a8ee95b-d3ba-43a2-93a9-08ed7965d63d, firstName: Mike, lastName: Kumm

I would like to extract similar strings of information for the rest of the new parties added - it should take the text value in the key field and append the text value; and so it goes until all is appended.

I do not want to specify a list of field beforehand - the program should report on whatever fields it get.

this is my existing xslt, with me starting to implement something of a solution under the part matching for CLIENTs:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:key name="party" match="newParty" use="@userId" />
<xsl:template match="@timeShift">
    <xsl:attribute name="timeShift">
        <xsl:call-template name="format-duration"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="format-duration">
<xsl:param name="value" select="." />
<xsl:param name="alwaysIncludeHours" select="false()" />
<xsl:param name="includeSeconds" select="true()" />
<xsl:if test="$value > 3600 or $alwaysIncludeHours">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number($value div 3600, '00'), ':')"/>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($value div 60 mod 60, '00')" />
<xsl:if test="$includeSeconds">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(':', format-number($value mod 60, '00'))" />
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/chatTranscript">
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webrecall/css/chat.css"/>
        </head>
        <header><xsl:value-of select="translate(@startAt, 'TZ', ' ')"/></header>

        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="newParty[userInfo/@userType='CLIENT']">
    <div class="ClientJoined" id="{@userId}">
        <label>Client: <xsl:value-of select="userInfo/@userNick" />
        </label>

        <label class="moreUserInfo">
             <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;', name(), ' | ')"/>
        </label>
        <label class="timeShiftLabel">
            <xsl:call-template name="format-duration">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="@timeShift"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </label>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="newParty[userInfo/@userType='AGENT']">
    <div class="AgentJoined" id="{@userId}">
        <label>Agent: <xsl:value-of select="userInfo/@userNick" /></label>
        <label class="timeShiftLabel">
            <xsl:call-template name="format-duration"><xsl:with-param name="value" select="@timeShift"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </label>
    </div>
</xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="newParty[userInfo/@userType='EXTERNAL']">
        <div class="SystemJoined" id="{@userId}">
            <label>System: <xsl:value-of select="userInfo/@userNick" /></label>
            <label class="timeShiftLabel System">
                <xsl:call-template name="format-duration">
                    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="@timeShift"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </label>
        </div>
    </xsl:template> 
        <xsl:template match="message">
            <xsl:variable name="party-class">
                <xsl:call-template name="lookup-class"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <div class="Messages {$party-class}" id="{@eventId}">
                <label><xsl:value-of select="msgText" /></label>
                <label class="timeShiftLabel">
                    <xsl:call-template name="format-duration">
                        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="@timeShift"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </label>
            </div>
        </xsl:template>   
        <xsl:template match="notice">
            <xsl:variable name="party-class">
                <xsl:call-template name="lookup-class"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <div class="Notices {$party-class}" id="{@eventId}">
                <label>
                    <xsl:value-of select="noticeText" />
                </label>
                <label class="timeShiftLabel">
                    <xsl:call-template name="format-duration">
                        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="@timeShift"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </label>
            </div>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="partyLeft">
        <xsl:variable name="party-class">
            <xsl:call-template name="lookup-class"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <div class="Notices {$party-class}" id="{@eventId}">
            <label><xsl:value-of select="reason" /></label>
            <label class="timeShiftLabel">
                <xsl:call-template name="format-duration">
                    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="@timeShift"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </label>
        </div>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="lookup-class">
            <xsl:variable name="party-type" select="key('party', @userId)/userInfo/@userType" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$party-type='CLIENT'">Client</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$party-type='AGENT'">Agent</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$party-type='EXTERNAL'">System</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor, which XSLT version can you use? And do you want plain text as the result format or somehow embed those key->value pairs in XML or HTML?

Comment: I'm using xslt 1.0. The text will be embedded into a label. I will add my existing xsl code - I did not want to add it, because there is a lot of it and might confuse the objective.

Answer (score 0):

The format of the required output is not quite clear. I am guessing you want to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="newParty[userInfo/@userType='CLIENT']">
    <div class="ClientJoined" id="{@userId}">
        <label>Client: <xsl:value-of select="userInfo/@userNick" />
        </label>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="userData/item"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <label>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@key, ': ', .)"/>
    </label>
</xsl:template>
```

which applied to your example input would return:

```
<div class="ClientJoined" id="0079581AF5590023">
   <label>Client: 10.50.24.202</label>
   <label>GMSServiceId: c0aa6221-d5f9-4fdc-9f75-ed63e99b1f12</label>
   <label>IdentifyCreateContact: 3</label>
   <label>MediaType: chat</label>
   <label>TimeZone: 120</label>
   <label>_data_id: 139-9a8ee95b-d3ba-43a2-93a9-08ed7965d63d</label>
   <label>firstName: Mike</label>
   <label>lastName: Kumm</label>
</div>
<div class="ClientJoined" id="007957F616780001">
   <label>Client: John Doe</label>
   <label>GMSServiceId: 5954d184-f89d-4f44-8c0f-a772d458b353</label>
   <label>IdentifyCreateContact: 3</label>
   <label>MediaType: chat</label>
   <label>TimeZone: 120</label>
   <label>_data_id: 139-e9826bf5-c5a4-40e5-a729-2cbdb4776a43</label>
   <label>firstName: John</label>
   <label>first_name: John</label>
   <label>lastName: Doe</label>
   <label>last_name: Doe</label>
   <label>location_lat: 37.8197</label>
   <label>location_long: -122.4786</label>
   <label>userDisplayName: John Doe</label>
</div>
<div class="ClientJoined" id="0079581874B50010">
   <label>Client: John</label>
   <label>EmailAddress: dskim@gmail.com</label>
   <label>FirstName: John</label>
   <label>IdentifyCreateContact: 3</label>
   <label>LastName: Doe</label>
   <label>MediaType: chat</label>
   <label>TimeZone: 120</label>
</div>
```

---

Note: if this is supposed to be an HTML `label` element, then I believe it's the wrong way to use it.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback; When I entered the math='type' code into my existing template, it complains that you cannot nest templates.

Comment: I am afraid I haven't got a clue what you mean by that. There is no  *math='type' code*  in my answer. Your stylesheet has a template matching `newParty[userInfo/@userType='CLIENT']`. You need to replace that template with mine, and add the template matching `item`.

Comment: Yes but I also need the existing code that is in the CLIENT matching template. I will sit with this some more...

Comment: @Harriet You should edit your question and add the **exact** output (**as code!**) you expect to get from the template  matching CLIENT (i.e. under the `<div class="ClientJoined">` tag).